# What does "frame up something" mean?

Tags: meaning

It's from this [video](https://youtu.be/Vn09c20wOmI). It's at 8 minutes and 40 seconds. Here it is:

> So I turned on the camera and **framed up** the shot with a nice big smile.

Comment: To frame a shot, the up is just colloquial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In filmmaking, **framing** refers to how you choose to compose a shot for
> a specific scene. Framing allows you to emphasize or show emotions,
> thoughts, sensations and ideas. It is the ingredient that adds weight
> and feeling to the moment.
>
> https://photography.tutsplus.com/tutorials/visual-expression-the-8-basic-ways-to-frame-shots-in-your-videos--cms-24641

To frame up a shot is the  same as to frame a shot.

Watch the video from the above website.

Answer (score 1):

Might the "up" be giving you trouble? It frequently complements a verb, usually underscoring an idea of completion. Sometimes, of course, it confers quite a different meaning from that of the original verb --

Completion: "Finish" / "finish up". The sense of "done and dusted" is stronger with the "up".

> Joan, redd up the parlour, I expect company this afternoon.

Different meaning:  "Give" / "give up".

In the sentence that you cite "up" does not alter the meaning of "frame".